# Impossible identity? $ \tan{\frac{x}{2}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\text{Let}\;\;t = \tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right). \;\;\text{Show that}\;\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{2}{1 + t^2}$$

I am saying that this is false because that identity is equal to $2\sec^2 x$ and that can't be equal. Also if I take the derivative of an integral I get the function so if I take the integral of a derivative I get the function also so the integral of that is $x + \sin x$ which evaluated at 0 is not equal to $\tan(x/2)$

Comment: Do you know what we get when we differentiate $\tan \theta$ with respect to $\theta$?

Comment: Yes, sec^2 is the differnetial

Comment: Now, the phrase "that identity is equal to $2 \sec^2$" is wrong. The identity is actually equal to $\frac{2}{\sec^2 x } $. Do you see that?

Comment: I am saying the derivative of t is that, and that is most definitely true.

Comment: @PaulthePirate, you seem to be pretty angry at some things: mathematics, rules, etc. This is not a wise attitude to try to learn stuff. About "how will you memorize all these rules": by understanding working and practicing them: there are no many short ways here. Now, about what you say "it is most definitely true": it is not, and perhaps you meant "false" instead "true". We have that $$\frac d{dx}\left(\tan\frac x2\right)=\frac12\frac1{\cos^2\frac x2}=\frac12\sec^2\frac x2$$ , so you can see it is most definitely not-true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that you seemed to have attempted finding $$\dfrac{dt}{dx} = \dfrac{d}{dx}\left( \tan \left(\frac x2\right)\right)= \frac 12 \sec^2\left(\frac x2\right)$$ However, the task at hand is to differentiate $f(t)$ with respect to $t$: i.e.,  $$\bf \dfrac{dx}{dt}\neq \dfrac{dt}{dx}$$
To obtain $\bf \dfrac{dx}{dt}$, we need to express $x$ as a function of $t$:

$$\begin{align} t & = \tan\left(\frac x2\right) \\  \arctan t & = \arctan\left(\tan \left(\frac x2\right)\right) \\ \arctan t + n\pi & = \frac x2 \\ \\  2\arctan t + 2n\pi & = x\end{align}$$

NOW we can find $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$: $$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}(2\arctan t + \underbrace{2n\pi}_{\text{constant}}) = \dfrac{2}{1 + t^2}$$

Comment: I don't follow the difference, it never makes sense, what comes first the function or the variable in those weird fraction notations?

Comment: The "function" is on top, the "variable" is on the bottom. I put these in quotes because often (as here) you have only a relation between two quantities, and you might want to think of either one as the variable. But in the identity you are proving, $x$ is the "function".

Comment: What you found was the derivative of $t$ with respect to $x$. That's $\dfrac{dt}{dx}$. You're asked to find the derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$: that's what's meant by $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$. So we need to find express $x = f(t)$, which we have as $x = \tan^{-1}(t) +...$. Recall the derivative of arctan t= ($\tan^{-1} t$)

Comment: That is absurd, how can I memorize all these little rules?

Comment: I know, it can be a handful, Paul.  See this link: [the inverse trig functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_tangent#Relationships_between_trigonometric_functions_and_inverse_trigonometric_functions) relate the the right triangle. You'll also get a refresher on the derivatives and integrals of the inverse trig functions.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: Or, if you need a way to do this that doesn't directly involve the arctangent, see my answer.

Comment: That is just stupid I think, there are 111 identities in the back of my book and another 40 in the front, I am not going to waste my time and memorize all of them. I would rather pursue something that challenges your intelligence, not your ability to memorize formulas.

Comment: I agree about seeking challenge for the intelligence, and not the ability to memorize!  This identity, though, turns out to be extremely useful for **lots** of integrals.

Comment: I don't follow that magic you did to get x. n seems pretty random as well.

Comment: (@PaulthePirate: you might find it helpful to latch onto a particular example. One I found helpful: suppose you're driving in your car, and you are at position $x$ at time $t$, then your velocity is $dx/dt$ ("the change in $x$ with respect to $t$"). Of course, $x$ varies with $t$, not vice-versa (you may revisit the same position at many different times, but not vice-versa). (If you drew a graph, you'd probably draw $t$ on the horizontal axis and $x$ on the vertical axis, showing that $t$ is somehow varying of its own accord and $x$ depends on $t$, right?))

Comment: Paul: would you have written $\frac{x}{2} = \tan^{-1}(t)$? If so, you're almost there. Look at the graph of $\tan$, and notice that adding $\pi$ doesn't change anything (i.e. $\tan(x/2) = \tan(x/2 + \pi)$ - so we can't quite work out which $x/2$ this $t$ came from, but we can work it out up to adding or subtracting a few $\pi$s.

Comment: Forget the $n\pi$ or $2n\pi$: that's just showing the periodicity. It's a constant (n denoting a multiple of $\pi$) so it's lost when differentiating. The rest is just using $tan \theta = t \implies \theta = \tan^{-1} t$, except in this case, $\theta = \frac x2$.

Comment: I don't follow at all, if I have f(x) = x^2 then they both depend on eachother.

Comment: Yes, but when we differentiate $y = f(x)$ to obtain $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, we differentiate with respect to $x$. Here we need $x = f(t) = 2\tan^{-1}t$, so we need to differentiate with respect to $t$ to find $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$. The variable appearing in the denominator of $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ is the one we differentiate the function with respect to: here, that's $t$.

Comment: With respect to means the variable?

Comment: Yes. That's right. As you see, we can write the given equation in terms of $x$, or in terms of $t$. In this particular case, since we're asked to find $\dfrac{dx}{d\bf t}$ we need to write x = "function of $t$". And then differentiate the function "with respect to $t$."

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another TU!!! +1

Comment: TU Amy :-) $++$

Answer (score 4):

Your confusion is that you're asked to find $\frac{dx}{dt}$, not $\frac{dt}{dx}$. Start with
$$
t=\tan\frac{x}{2}
$$
Differentiate both sides with respect to $t$. Using the chain rule twice you'll have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dt}{dt}=1&=\sec^2\frac{x}{2}\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\\
&=\sec^2\frac{x}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}
\end{align}
$$
so, multiplying both sides by 2 and dividing by $\sec^2(x/2)$ we get
$$
2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}=\frac{dx}{dt}
$$
and when $\tan\alpha= t$ we have $\cos\alpha = 1/\sqrt{t^2+1}$ (draw a triangle), so
$$
\cos\frac{x}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}
$$
so we have, from the above displayed equation,
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{2}{t^2+1}
$$
as required.

This technique is known as [implicit differentiation](http://web.mit.edu/wwmath/calculus/differentiation/implicit.html) and is very useful in cases like this where you don't have a function defined in terms of the variable with which you want to differentiate.

Answer (score 2):

Let us rewrite what you have with some added notation. You are given 
$$
t(x)=\tan(x/2),
$$
a function of $x$. You are asked to find the derivative of the function $x$ with respect to the variable $t$. You must first express $x$ as a function of $t$. As other have mentionned, taking $\tan^{-1}$ on both sides yields
$$
\frac{x}{2}=\tan^{-1}(t)+n\pi.
$$
Note that the $n\pi$ is there because of the periodicity of $\tan$, but won't change a thing when we differentiate with respect to $t$.

Now we have
$$
x(t)=\tan^{-1}(t)+2n\pi
$$
and we can find
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{2}{1+t^2}
$$
provided you know the derivative of $\tan^{-1}(t)$.

Comment: I don't and I also don't follow how to convert t into x and such.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong, the identity is correct.  Note that $t = \tan(x/2)$ implies
$x = 2 \arctan(t) + 2 n \pi$.

Comment: I don't follow that implication.

Comment: What properties of arctan do you know?

Answer (score 1):

Paul. You've asked a couple of nice questions here, if I understand you right:

> 1) Given that $t$ can be expressed as a function of $x$ (specifically, you asked about the case where $t = \tan(\frac{x}{2})$), how can we find $\frac{dx}{dt}$, if it exists?
>
> 2) If we know that $\tan(\frac{x}{2}) = t$, then why does $x = 2\arctan(t) + 2n\pi$?

The answer to the first question comes from the chain rule. By the chain rule, we can write

$$\frac{dx}{dx} = \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx};$$

since we know that $\frac{dx}{dx} = 1$, this tells us that

$$ 1 = \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx} \implies \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1}{\frac{dt}{dx}}.$$

(This proof assumes that $x$ can be expressed as a differentiable function of $t$, but that assumption is valid here, so all is well.)

In your case, we see that

$$ t = \tan(\frac{x}{2}) \implies \frac{dt}{dx} = \sec^2(\frac{x}{2}) \cdot \frac{1}{2} $$

by the chain rule, and so

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1}{\frac{dt}{dx}} = \frac{2}{\sec^2(\frac{x}{2})}$$

But $\sec^2(x) = 1 + \tan^2(x)$, and so

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{2}{\sec^2(\frac{x}{2})} = \frac{2}{1 + \tan^2(\frac{x}{2})} = \frac{2}{1 + t^2} $$

where to get the last equality I just plugged in $\tan(\frac{x}{2}) = t$.

Your second question has a fairly simple answer: the $\arctan(t)$ function as mathematicians usually define it outputs an angle $\theta$ between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$, such that $\tan(\theta)$ = $t$. We have to bear in mind that, when we take $\arctan(\tan(\frac{x}{2}))$, we may not get back $\frac{x}{2}$ - just $\theta$. However, we know for certain that $\frac{x}{2} = \theta + n\pi$ for some integer $n$ and some $\theta$ between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (ponder this if it is not clear). This $\theta$ will be precisely the one which $\arctan$ returns for the argument $t = \tan(\frac{x}{2})$, and so this $\theta$ is $\arctan(t)$. Thus,

$$\frac{x}{2} = \arctan(t) + n\pi$$

which is the second thing you were having trouble with.

Hope this helps!